# script running from powershell window but not fromfile

Tags: powershell

I am running this script and it works fine from powershell window but when I put it in a file it does not work. I have enabled powershell to run scripts on my system and I dont receive any error. I guess it is happining because of break command. How can I run it from a file?

```
Get-ChildItem  C:\* -Include  'config.xml' -Recurse | Foreach-Object {$file = $_; break}

Get-WinEvent -FilterXml ([xml](Get-Content "$file")) | format-table TimeCreated, Message -autosize -HideTableHeaders >C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\report.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

save file as script_name.ps1

open Powershell, and navigate to directory that file is located in and type ".\script_name.ps1"

See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176949.aspx